# Python command to run function on directories specified in a text file

Tags: python, command-line, directory

I have a text file called "folders" and in it lists directories that I want to run a function on (can include wildcards).

folders.txt:

```
Images*\        //Any folders that start with Images)
Music\Rap       //The specific folder Music\Rap)
Video\Horror    //The specific folder Video\Horror)
```

Python code:

```
directories = folders.readlines()
for lines in directories:
  lines = lines.strip()
  command= 'dir ' + RootPath + '\\' +  lines + ' /B'
  result = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
  for line in result.split('\r\n'):
     Execute function
```

I decided to use the dir command cause that was the only way I knew how to handle wildcards. But running "dir c:\Music\Rap /B" would list all the files inside that directory rather than the directory itself. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: use `glob`, it will return match

Comment: use `os.listdir` or `os.walk` if you need to  search subdirectories

Answer (score 0):

The `glob` module contains methods for expanding wildcards according to the filesystem content. Example:

```
import glob
result = glob.glob( 'Images*' )
```